# Induced subgraphs of small strongly regular graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a strongly regular graph $G$ with parameters $(76,30,8,14).$ Hoffman's bound tells us that $\overline{G}$ has an independent set of size at most $4$ and its not hard to see there are indeed $4$ independent vertices in $\overline{G}.$

So if $x \in V(G)$ then the graph $H$ induced by $N(v)$ is a $8$-regular, $K_4$-free graph on $30$ vertices and known bounds tell us that $\alpha(H) \ge 5.$

Hence $G$ must must contain $K_{1,5}$ as an induced subgraph. I do not see any way to extend this subgraph without introducing cases.

What I am wondering is

> ***Question 1.*** Can someone construct larger graphs that must be present as induced subgraphs of $G$

and

> ***Question 2.*** Can someone find large induced subgraphs for some of the missing SRG's on less than 100 vertices?

The motivating factor for this problem is that getting an induced subgraph of order 19 not having $2$ as an eigenvalue is enough to reconstruct $G.$

Comment: What will you reconstruct if the SRG is not unique?

Comment: @joro If one can find an unique such graph then the method in question will give you all possibilites. Though my hope is to start with a large induced subgraph and extend it to many candidates of order 19.

Comment: in my old papers I reconstructed subgraphs induced on the common neighbours of a pair of non-adjacent vertices. But it was always the case that I knew much more about $N(v)$ than here.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Speaking of this concrete case... Using interlacing for pruning one can construct the graphs induced by $N(v) \cap N(u)$ for adjacent as well as non-adjacent vertices. I have both lists. I'll check if your paper offers any insights how to go from there :-)

Comment: @Jernej : basically, it might be possible to reconstruct all the possibilities for $N(v)$ using your lists (provided they aren't very long...). And this would be almost it (again, depending upon how long the resulting list is).

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Non-adjacent vertices give 375219 candidates. Adjacent one 266. Do you think that would be doable?

Comment: Can you use your candidates to enumerate possibilities for $N(v)\cap N(u)\cap N(w)$, for $u,w\in N(v)$ ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Hm.. Did you perhaps mean that only $w \in N(v)?$ If not then there are precisely three possible graphs induced by $N(v) \cap N(u) \cap N(w)$ - $K_1$ or $2K_1$ and $\emptyset$

Comment: No, I meant just that - but how do these cases depend upon $u$ and $w$ being adjacent?

Answer (score 2):

On strategies of reconstructing bigger subgraphs: suppose
for a vertex $v$ we have we know the set $M$ of (possible) subgraphs $G(v,w)$ induced on $N(v,w):=N(v)\cap N(w)$, for a vertex $w$ at distance 2 from $v$, and the set $\Lambda$ of (possible) subgraphs $G(v,u)$ induced on $N(v,u)$, for $u\in N(v)$.

Take $H\in M$ and $F\in\Lambda$ so that they match on $N(u,v)$ and on $N(u,w)$, for $w\in N(u)-N(v)$ (i.e. we identify $H$ with  $G(v,w)$ and $F$ with $G(v,u)$). Now, let us pick $w\neq w_1\in N(u)-N(v)$, and go though all the possible $H_1\in M$ so that in addition $H_1$ can be identified with $G(v,w_1)$; for each success we can further pick $w_2\in N(u)-N(v)-\{w,w'\}$ and
go through all the possible $H_2\in M$ so that $H_2$ can be identified with $G(v,w_2)$, etc. 
One possible variation here is to switch the roles of $u$ and $v$ and reconstruct subgraphs in $N(u)$ in the same vein.

If such a search tree does not get too big, one can think of what to do next.

Comment: Let me restate the precise fact here. If $u \sim v$ and $w \in N(u) \cap N(v)$ then $|N(u) \cap N(v) \cap N(w) | \leq 2$ In particular the induced subgraph is either empty, $K_1$ or $2K_1.$

Comment: So, how about $u\neq w\not\in N(u)$, but $w\in N(v)$? This is what you can extract from that 375219 examples...

Comment: I'll be able to give this result soon (an hour or so) - I am recomputing the list of graphs induced by $N(u) \cap N(v)$ when $u \not \sim v.$ Fingers crossed we get the same bound.

Comment: Is the number 266 simply the total number of 8-vertex graphs of maximal degree 2?

Comment: That number was in fact incorrect. The correct number is 6.

Comment: I don't know if the condition that the neighbourhood of each vertex in each of these 375s219 subgraphs is a subgraph of one of these 6 graphs on 8 vertices is satisfied automatically, or you already checked it. But it's worth looking at, just in case.

Comment: Actually that would give the 266 graphs on 8 vertices.

Comment: thus you are saying that 375219 can pruned quite a bit, right? Or it's 266 subgraphs of these 6 graphs on 8 vertices?

Comment: Not sure. If we take $u \not \sim v$ and consider the induced subgraph for $X \subset N(u) \cap N(v)$  of cardinality 8 then we get 266 candidates. If we take the full set, they should give a list of the 375219 that I am now re-computing (should be very soon now)

Comment: Okay so here it is. If $u \not \sim v$ and $w \in N(u) \cap N(v)$ then there 7 possible graphs induced by $N(u) \cap N(v) \cap N(w)$ and they have cardinality at most $5$

Comment: Did you check that each of these 7 graphs is a subgraph of one of the six 8-vertex graphs from your list of possible subgraphs for $N(v)\cap N(w)$? Anyhow, one may try to extend the neighbourhood $N_v(w)$ of $w$ in $N(v)$ and reconstruct the missing edges between  $N_v(w)$ and the other 14 vertices. If it gives you something without eigenvalue 2, you're done, as you get at least 19-vertex subgraph this way.

Comment: Yes, each of these 7 subgraphs is a subgraph of the 8-vertex graphs. The problem with extending to graphs of order 19 is that there are many cases having 2 as eig. What I do know though is that if an induced subgraph does not have 2 as an eig then it can be extended to a valid subgraph of order 19 without 2 as an eig. Out of this large list there are 7070 graphs that have 2 as eig. Do you think that is small enough to attempt reconstructing $N(v)$?

Comment: Do you really need to reconstruct the whole $N(v)$ in these cases? Or just enough vertices to get a subgraph with 19 eigenvalues not equal to 2?

Comment: Such a graph would indeed be enough. The problem is that if you start with these graphs on 16 vertices that do contain 2 as an eigenvalue it may happen that they "keep" 2 as an eigenvalue in the extended graphs of order 19.

Comment: 7000 cases does not look as scary as 375000 cases, but still is not small. It depends of course on how big will be search trees when we extend...

Comment: If you can describe the general idea of computing $N(v)$ (perhaps in this answer) I can try. Interlacing is good at pruning intermediate graphs so as long as we can produce induced subgraphs it may be worth a try.